# How to Return Object using HQL query resultset in Openbravo

Tags: object, return, hql, hibernate-criteria, openbravo

Hi I am openbravo beginner. I would like to know about the returning object from HQL query resultset. Normally I could return list or string. When I am trying to return Object its showing error like cannot cast object to string.

Here my object is : ShipmentInOut

```
private ShipmentInOut getShipment(String documentNo) {
    String query = "select id from MaterialMgmtShipmentInOut where documentNo='" + documentNo
            + "' and salesTransaction='Y'";
        Query resultset = OBDal.getInstance().getSession().createQuery(query);

        List<ShipmentInOut> shpmntCritList = resultset.list();


        if (shpmntCritList != null && shpmntCritList.size() > 0) {
          return shpmntCritList.get(0);
        } else {
          throw new OBException("shipment " + documentNo + " not found");
        }
}
```

In the above statment I got exception so i decided to do criteria query and i wrote criteria query equalent to above HQL query but unfortunatly if condition second part is returning 0 as 
result. But I dont know why I am getting different result in same kind of query. The above HQL query is properly entering into if condition. but the problem is casting.

```
 private ShipmentInOut getShipment(String documentNo) {

     log.info()
    OBCriteria<ShipmentInOut> shpmntCrit = OBDal.getInstance().createCriteria(ShipmentInOut.class);
    shpmntCrit.add(Restrictions.eq(ShipmentInOut.PROPERTY_DOCUMENTNO, documentNo));
    shpmntCrit.add(Restrictions.eq(ShipmentInOut.PROPERTY_SALESTRANSACTION, true));


    List<ShipmentInOut> shpmntCritList = shpmntCrit.list();
    if (shpmntCritList != null && shpmntCritList.size() > 0) {
      return shpmntCritList.get(0);
    } else {
      throw new OBException("shipment " + documentNo + " not found");
    }
  }
```

Please any one help me. I would like to implement any one of above method. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not provided the class mappings

Comment: HQL should definately return you the object. and in Which line are you getting error?

Answer (score 0):

At what line are you getting error?

try this

```
 //log.info()
 OBCriteria<ShipmentInOut> shpmntCrit =  OBDal.getInstance().createCriteria(ShipmentInOut.class);
 shpmntCrit.add(Restrictions.eq(ShipmentInOut.PROPERTY_DOCUMENTNO, documentNo));
 shpmntCrit.add(Restrictions.eq(ShipmentInOut.PROPERTY_SALESTRANSACTION, true));

 if (shpmntCrit.list().size() > 0)
   return shpmntCrit.list().get(0);
 else
   throw new OBException("shipment " + documentNo + " not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer. Finally I got solution by own

```
String query = "from MaterialMgmtShipmentInOut where documentNo='" + documentNo
        + "' and salesTransaction='Y'";
    Query resultset = OBDal.getInstance().getSession().createQuery(query);
    List<ShipmentInOut> resultlist = new ArrayList<ShipmentInOut>(resultset.list());
    if (resultset.list().size() > 0) {
      return resultlist.get(0);
    } else {
      throw new OBException("shipment " + documentNo + " not found");
    }
```